# Text is placed over a template image

Tags: graphics

I have created a beamer presentation. I add the following code in my .tex:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.85\textwidth, 0.1cm)
{\transparent{0.2}\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{img/large.png}}
\end{textblock*}}
```

in order to add a logo image in every slide. My problem is that when I add text to every slide sometimes the text is going over the logo. How can I avoid that colission of text and image?